# flutter camera not reinitializing on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, camera

I need to use camera in two screens when one screen push another screen.

In that case the camera shows black screen when I go back from second widget:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];
late CameraDescription firstCamera;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TakePictureScreen(
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// A screen that allows users to take a picture using a given camera.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TakePictureScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.camera,
  });

  final CameraDescription camera;

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  late CameraController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      enableAudio: false,
    );
    _controller?.initialize().then((value) => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _controller?.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Take a picture')),
      body: _controller != null && _controller!.value.isInitialized
          ? CameraPreview(_controller!)
          : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
            // final oldController = _controller;
            // setState(() => _controller = null);
            // await oldController?.dispose();
            // var cameras = await availableCameras();
            // var firstCamera = cameras.first;
            await navigator.push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TakePictureScreen(
                  camera: firstCamera,
                ),
              ),
            );
            // cameras = await availableCameras();
            // firstCamera = cameras.first;
            // _controller = CameraController(
            //   widget.camera,
            //   ResolutionPreset.medium,
            //   enableAudio: false,
            // );
            await _controller?.initialize();
            setState(() {});
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried everything (see commented out code) but didn't succeed.

The only way is to pass controller as a parameter, but I can not do it in my project.

There is no such problem on android.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the camera initialization into a separate _initializeCamera() function to make it easier to call

Properly dispose of the camera controller in the dispose() method of the _TakePictureScreenState class.

Re-initialize the camera controller in the onPressed callback of the floating action button after returning from the second screen.

Comment: The answer is wrong and I think it was generated by chat gpt. Please remove it

Comment: No it wasn't lol

Comment: please add the code which works on ios

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following to ios/Runner/Info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>your usage description here</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>your usage description here</string>
```

2. Create controller and initialize it.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final cameras = await availableCameras();

  final controller = CameraController(
    cameras[0],
    ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh,
    enableAudio: false,
  );

  await controller.initialize();

  runApp(
    CameraProvider(
      controller: controller,
      child: const MaterialApp(home: FirstScreen()),
    ),
  );
}
```

3. Use parent widget to manage controller lifecycle and access:

```
class CameraProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  const CameraProvider({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required super.child,
  });

  final CameraController controller;

  static CameraProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    final cameraProvider =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<CameraProvider>();

    assert(cameraProvider != null, "$CameraProvider not found in context.");

    return cameraProvider!;
  }

  /// Call when finished using camera (i.e. in stateful widget dispose method).
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CameraProvider oldWidget) {
    return controller != oldWidget.controller;
  }
}
```

4. Use context to access shared controller in different routes/screens:

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            /// Context access through InheritedWidget.
            CameraProvider.of(context).controller.buildPreview(),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen()),
                ),
                heroTag: null,
                child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            /// Context access through InheritedWidget.
            CameraProvider.of(context).controller.buildPreview(),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                heroTag: null,
                child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using the same controller in the both screens. I need to have different controllers

Comment: Then create a `secondController` class member in the same way the first one is created, pass it to `CameraProvider`, and access with `CameraProvider.of(context).secondController`. Also, add it to the `dispose` method.